# Find a site through Google search with a specific word in its domain name

Tags: google-search

I forgot the domain name of the site I'm looking for, however, I know a word that is part of the domain.

How do I use Google to find a site with a specific word in its domain name?

I tried using `inurl:{keyword} site:.com` but it's also showing the result having that particular word as the part of the full URL.

Comment: Checked browser history?

Comment: @Xen2050 I read the domain name of the site somewhere else.

Comment: I don't think google doesn't let you use regex for their searches (not even for your own gmail), but maybe the word you know plus some descriptive words about the website would find it... article topic it was on, etc?

Answer (score 3):

You wrote `site:.com` which I think is not that accurate.
Try searching like this: inurl:`xxx` + `.com` + `SomeOtherTags`
This will show you at least the name of that website. ALSO note the spaces between plus signs and add tags with caution .
For Example: I wanna find blogger I write: `inurl:blog + .com + google` and the fifth result is that.